# Remove object from nested tree if it doesn't match any of the selected id

Tags: javascript, tree, traversal, depth-first-search, postorder

I have a selected array

```
this.selectedArray = ["1:Tree", "2:PT", "5:PT - DD", "11:PT - C", "3:SAC", "7:SAC - DR", "6:SAC - DDE"]
```

and Tree structure with children:

```
this.root =    
{"children": [
   {"children": [
     {
      "children": [],
      "id": 12,
      "name": "PT - D"
    },
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "children": [],
          "id": 8,
          "name": "PT-33"
        },
        {
          "children": [],
          "id": 10,
          "name": "PT-62"
        },
        {
          "children": [],
          "id": 9,
          "name": "PT-52"
        }
      ],
      "id": 4,
      "name": "PT - 32"
    },
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "children": [],
          "id": 11,
          "name": "PT - C"
        }
      ],
      "id": 5,
      "name": "PT - DD"
    }
  ],
  "id": 2,
  "name": "PT"
},
{
  "children": [
    {
      "children": [],
      "id": 7,
      "name": "SAC - DR"
    },
    {
      "children": [],
      "id": 6,
      "name": "SAC - DE"
    }
  ],
  "id": 3,
  "name": "SAC"
}
],
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Tree"
}
```

I would like to remove the node from the tree if the node.Id + ':' + node.name doesn't match any of the items in this.selectedArray.

I am having trouble finding an algorithm that will allow me to delete all the object data which doesn't match any of the item in this.selected from the deeply nested tree.

Here is the code:

```
 setSearchResult(selectedArray) {
    if (!!selected) {
        let this.tree = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.root));
        this.topLevelGroups = this.removeFromTree(this.tree, selectedArray, null, null);
    }
}

removeFromTree(parent, selectedArray, grandParent, idx) {
    let { name, id, children } = parent;
    let parentId = id + ':' + name;
    if (!!selectedArray) {
        if (!selectedArray.includes(parentId)) {
            if (grandParent) {
                grandParent.children.splice(idx, 1);
            } 
            else return null;
        }
        if (!!parent && !!children) {
            for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                this.removeFromTree(children[i], selectedArray, parent, i);
            }
        }
    }
    return this.tree.children;
  }
```

I think the problem is after executing code which has this.slice, it will return and doesn't go to its sibling. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: are the nodes sorted in the selected array? please add the wanted result.

Comment: selected array not sorted. wanted result is any of the node.id+':'+node.name which match any of the item in the selectedArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a nonmutating approach and reduce the array by respecting the children.

This solution takes a hash table for the wanted `id` as key and `name` as value from the splitted values of the `selected` array.

As result only known nodes are included.

```js
const
    filter = (r, { children = [], ...o }) => {
        if (nodes[o.id] !== o.name) return r;
        children = children.reduce(filter, []);
        r.push(children.length ? { ...o, children } : o);
        return r;
    },
    selected = ["1:Tree", "2:PT", "5:PT - DD", "11:PT - C", "3:SAC", "7:SAC - DR", "6:SAC - DDE"],
    nodes = selected.reduce((r, s) => {
        var [k, v] = s.split(':');
        r[k] = v;
        return r;
    }, {}),
    tree = { children: [{ children: [{ children: [], id: 12, name: "PT - D" }, { children: [{ children: [], id: 8, name: "PT-33" }, { children: [], id: 10, name: "PT-62" }, { children: [], id: 9, name: "PT-52" }], id: 4, name: "PT - 32" }, { children: [{ children: [], id: 11, name: "PT - C" }], id: 5, name: "PT - DD" }], id: 2, name: "PT" }, { children: [{ children: [], id: 7, name: "SAC - DR" }, { children: [], id: 6, name: "SAC - DE" }], id: 3, name: "SAC" }], id: 1, name: "Tree" },
    result = tree.children = tree.children.reduce(filter, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is recursive DFS method which could use? if possible would like to modify slightly the above attempted DFS solution in the question

Comment: the building of children is dfs. do you like to remove empty children? or what is the target of your question?

Comment: i would like to remove the children from its parent if the children doesn't match any item of the selectedArray

Comment: is wondering if you know this. I have been trying to solve this but couldn't.  instead I resorted to use DFS to search the tree and output the matched node and its parent/ancestor to the above selectedArray and then loop through the tree again to remove the non match item . Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102867/javascript-tree-search-algorithm-which-return-subset-of-the-tree-which-contains

Comment: i didn't understand the question, so no answer from me.

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive filter function, because you use strings in your `selectedArray` you can easily use `Set` to test
a node.

```
const tags = new Set(selectedArray);

function filterArray ({ children, id, name }) {
    const tag = `${id}:${name}`;
    if (tags.has(tag)) {
        return {
            id,
            name,
            children: children.map(filterArray).filter((child) => child !== null)
        };
    }
    return null;
}


const output = filterArray(root);
console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 4));
```